# Template specialization with macros

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I'm looking at the following [function](https://github.com/pytorch/FBGEMM/blob/main/src/QuantUtils.cc#L397-L414), reproduced below

```
#define FBGEMM_SPECIALIZED_REQUANTIZE(T)                            \
  template <>                                                       \
  FBGEMM_API void Requantize<T>(                                    \
      const int32_t* src,                                           \
      T* dst,                                                       \
      const int64_t len,                                            \
      const RequantizationParams& params,                           \
      int thread_id,                                                \
      int num_threads) {                                            \
    int64_t i_begin, i_end;                                         \
    fbgemmPartition1D(thread_id, num_threads, len, i_begin, i_end); \
    for (int64_t i = i_begin; i < i_end; ++i) {                     \
      dst[i] = Requantize<T>(src[i], params);                       \
    }                                                               \
  }
FBGEMM_SPECIALIZED_REQUANTIZE(uint16_t)
FBGEMM_SPECIALIZED_REQUANTIZE(int32_t)
#undef FBGEMM_SPECIALIZED_REQUANTIZE
```

It appears to be using a macro to specialize the functions.

I'm wondering what is the difference between doing that vs. no macros and just specializing everything like usual in C++?

Comment: please include all necessary code in the question to make it self contained. Links to external sites can break

Comment: Macros just perform text substitution, so there's no difference except less typing.

Comment: perhaps the author was afraid of arcane looking code that was required to get the same specialization for two different types. I believe with concepts it can be done without arcane code, but also before it was possible without duplication. And with macros you always get some degree of obfuscation.

Comment: In this case it may be preferrable to add a helper template for this kind of specialization to avoid the use of the macro: `template<>void Requantize<uint16_t>(...) {RequantizeHelper<T>(...);} template<>void Requantize<int32_t>(...) {RequantizeHelper<int32_t>(...);}` or alternatively use sfinae/concepts, but this would require a bit more typing, but is imho worth it...

Comment: It's curious they chose specialisation. It seems doable with explicit instantiation. No macros needed. Unless there's a primary template that does something useful.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yeah, I'm not sure the purpose of specialization here since they have the same code for all the types. I see this pattern used in that entire file. not sure what the reason is

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, macros are merely about text replacement (more precisely: tokens). Macros cannot do something that more typing cannot do as well. Instead of

```
FBGEMM_SPECIALIZED_REQUANTIZE(uint16_t)
FBGEMM_SPECIALIZED_REQUANTIZE(int32_t)
```

The author could have spelled out the two specializations without using any macro. However, this would lead to code duplication. This on the other hand can be avoided, as mentioned by fabian via:

```
template <typename T>                                                    
void Helper(const int32_t* src,                                           
  T* dst,                                                       
  const int64_t len,                                            
  const RequantizationParams& params,                           
  int thread_id,                                                
  int num_threads) {
   // code here
}
```

and then

```
template <>                                                       
FBGEMM_API void Requantize<uint16_t>(const int32_t* src,                                           
  uint16_t* dst,                                                       
  const int64_t len,                                            
  const RequantizationParams& params,                           
  int thread_id,                                                
  int num_threads) { Helper<uint16_t>(src,dst,len,params,thread_id,num_threads); }
```

And same specialization for `int32_t`. Note how already the argument list of the function leads to lots of repetition. Macros are usually avoided because they lead to obfuscation, code duplication is usually avoided because it leads to hard to maintain code. Its a trade off to be made.

The other alternative to specialize for two different types at once is to use sfinae, but that requires to modify the primary template which may not be desirable. Or concepts but they are only available since C++20.

---

Anyhow...

> I'm wondering what is the difference between doing that vs. no macros and just specializing everything like usual in C++?

The amount of typing.

Answer (score 0):

First we should start from [original template](https://github.com/pytorch/FBGEMM/blob/f7050c9fcfaa2c276ff8512e6cdd19c378bcba53/include/fbgemm/QuantUtils.h#L248-L255):

```cpp
template <typename T>
FBGEMM_API void Requantize(
    const std::int32_t* src,
    T* dst,
    std::int64_t len,
    const RequantizationParams& params,
    int thread_id = 0,
    int num_threads = 1);
```

Note this template is only declared. I can't find implementation of it. Note it is in a header file.

There is also [alternative specialization for `uint8_t`](https://github.com/pytorch/FBGEMM/blob/main/src/QuantUtils.cc#L416-L434).

Now author planed to make it work only for two types: `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` and `int32_t`.

You can see this, since macro `FBGEMM_SPECIALIZED_REQUANTIZE` is [defined](https://github.com/pytorch/FBGEMM/blob/main/src/QuantUtils.cc#L397-L411) then after those two usages it is immediately [undefined](https://github.com/pytorch/FBGEMM/blob/main/src/QuantUtils.cc#L414).

So question how this behaves in current state?

- if user of library uses this template with pointer to type which is not supported (is not one of types: `uint8_t`, `uint16_t` and `int32_t`), it will get linker error: "undefined reference to function tempalte .....".
- if user of library uses this temple with a pointer of `uint8_t` one implementation will be used and other implementation will be used for `uint16_t` and `int32_t`.

Is this good? IMO not it is better to get compilation error instead linking error. Note that during development of new code, until this code is not in use (for example test written) build can pass, then when you add test or use new functionality then you got linker error.

Can this be done better? YES!

But it depends on requirements. One way to solve this is this way:
In header file have overloaded old fashioned functions:

```cpp
FBGEMM_API void Requantize(
    const std::int32_t* src,
    uint8_t* dst,
    std::int64_t len,
    const RequantizationParams& params,
    int thread_id = 0,
    int num_threads = 1);

FBGEMM_API void Requantize(
    const std::int32_t* src,
    uint16_t* dst,
    std::int64_t len,
    const RequantizationParams& params,
    int thread_id = 0,
    int num_threads = 1);

FBGEMM_API void Requantize(
    const std::int32_t* src,
    int32_t* dst,
    std::int64_t len,
    const RequantizationParams& params,
    int thread_id = 0,
    int num_threads = 1);
```

Then in cpp file define template and just use it inside of this functions:

```cpp
// this one has own version
FBGEMM_API void Requantize(
    const std::int32_t* src,
    uint8_t* dst,
    std::int64_t len,
    const RequantizationParams& params,
    int thread_id = 0,
    int num_threads = 1) {
  int64_t i_begin, i_end;
  fbgemmPartition1D(thread_id, num_threads, len, i_begin, i_end);
  if (params.target_qparams.precision == 8 && cpuinfo_initialize() &&
      fbgemmHasAvx2Support()) {
    RequantizeAvx2(&src[i_begin], &dst[i_begin], i_end - i_begin, params);
  } else {
    for (int64_t i = i_begin; i < i_end; ++i) {
      dst[i] = Requantize<uint8_t>(src[i], params);
    }
  }
}

namespace detail {
  template <typename T>
  FBGEMM_API void Requantize<T>(
      const int32_t* src,
      T* dst,
      const int64_t len,
      const RequantizationParams& params,
      int thread_id,
      int num_threads) {
    int64_t i_begin, i_end;
    fbgemmPartition1D(thread_id, num_threads, len, i_begin, i_end);
    for (int64_t i = i_begin; i < i_end; ++i) {
      dst[i] = Requantize<T>(src[i], params);
    }
  }
} // namespace detail

FBGEMM_API void Requantize(
    const std::int32_t* src,
    uint16_t* dst,
    std::int64_t len,
    const RequantizationParams& params,
    int thread_id = 0,
    int num_threads = 1) {
    detail::Requantize(src, dst, len, params, thread_id, num_threads);
}

FBGEMM_API void Requantize(
    const std::int32_t* src,
    int32_t* dst,
    std::int64_t len,
    const RequantizationParams& params,
    int thread_id = 0,
    int num_threads = 1) {
    detail::Requantize(src, dst, len, params, thread_id, num_threads);
}
```

Now linker errors are replaced with compilation errors and macros are not needed.

---

Other way to do it is keep template declaration in header file and define it in cpp file providing specialization for `uint8_t`.
So header file unchanged and in cpp:

```cpp
  template <typename T>
  FBGEMM_API void Requantize<T>(
      const int32_t* src,
      T* dst,
      const int64_t len,
      const RequantizationParams& params,
      int thread_id,
      int num_threads) {
    int64_t i_begin, i_end;
    fbgemmPartition1D(thread_id, num_threads, len, i_begin, i_end);
    for (int64_t i = i_begin; i < i_end; ++i) {
      dst[i] = Requantize<T>(src[i], params);
    }
  }

template<>
FBGEMM_API void Requantize<uint8_t>(
    const std::int32_t* src,
    uint8_t* dst,
    std::int64_t len,
    const RequantizationParams& params,
    int thread_id = 0,
    int num_threads = 1) {
  int64_t i_begin, i_end;
  fbgemmPartition1D(thread_id, num_threads, len, i_begin, i_end);
  if (params.target_qparams.precision == 8 && cpuinfo_initialize() &&
      fbgemmHasAvx2Support()) {
    RequantizeAvx2(&src[i_begin], &dst[i_begin], i_end - i_begin, params);
  } else {
    for (int64_t i = i_begin; i < i_end; ++i) {
      dst[i] = Requantize<uint8_t>(src[i], params);
    }
  }
}

tempalte Requantize<uint16_t>;
tempalte Requantize<int32_t>;
```

but I do not know how this interacts with other overloads of `Requantize`.

Comment: btw, what is the name of `tempalte Requantize<uint16_t>;`. I always get my template terminology mixed up. Is it instantiation in this case?

Comment: yes it is template instantiation.